# I am trying to pass a value from a view to a controller function

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, post, controller

> I am trying to pass a value from a view to a controller function 'update_action' and then
>   i need to $_POST from controller function 'update_action' to function 'update'
>   in  another controller. this is my code

---

```
public function update_action($Var_Code,$Var_Id)
    { 

           $id_ref = $this->input->post('Number',TRUE);
            $Code = $this->input->post('Code',TRUE);
           $_link = 'transaction/update/'.$Var_Code.'/'.$id_ref ; 
            redirect(site_($_link ));
      }
At another controller `my code here` 

    public function update( $Code,$id) 
    {        
        if (!empty($_POST)) 
        { 
 // run true code 
  $this->template->load('template','transaction_form', $data);
        }
     }else
        {

$this->template->load('template', 'error_pages', null);
        }
```

the problem is , i can't send $_post from update_action to   update
when i run my code always load "error_pages" . i can't access my transaction_form

Comment: As soon as you redirect you lose Post. Do what you need in the same controller.

Comment: expanding on @cartalot, if you have stuff you run from many controllers, put it in a library that all the controllers can load (or implement it as a trait). `redirect` is the worst `goto` code could have.

Comment: @jerry well said, although i would also suggest to consider refactoring to  Model(s), then to a Library if necessary.